# IE9 no muestra familia de fuente

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

Estoy haciendo una página web y quiero utilizar la fuente *nexa bold*, he descargado la fuente y la tengo en diversas extensiones como son `.otf`, `.eot`, `.wof`, `.ttf`, y `.svg`, quiero aclarar que este error solo lo tengo en Internet Explorer

Enseguida muestro el código CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: Nexa-Bold;
src:url(../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.otf) format("opentype"),
    url(../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.eot?#iefix) format("embedded-opentype"),
    url(../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.wof) format("wof"),
    url(../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.ttf) format("truetype"),
    url(../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.svg#svgFontName) format("svg");
```

}

Leyendo en internet encontré que en la extensión `.eot` se pone `?#iefix` para que no crashee pero aún así no funciona. Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar la versión de IE?

Answer (score 2):

Listo, funciono correctamente de la siguiente manera.

```
  @font-face {
font-family: 'Nexa-Bold';
src: url('../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),/*IE*/
    url('../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/nexa/NexaBold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg');
```

}